# How to config AWS CodeCommit config file for an specific repo

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, aws-codecommit

Im having the following issue. As part of my job, I handle multiple AWS Accounts, each of which have a separate AWS CodeCommit repos and account-specific IAM Users (which result on different User IDs)

I want to find a way that I can config my ssh to access different accounts depending on the repo

Currently it works correctly, as my config file looks like this:

```
  Host git-codecommit.*.amazonaws.com
     User APKAEIBAERJR2EXAMPLE
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/codecommit_rsa
```

What I need, is to be able to add different repos that use different accounts so that I don't have to edit the config file everytime I switch from one project to another i.e.

```
#Use this User ID and ssh-key for repo A
Host git-codecommit.*.amazonaws.com 
  User IAMUSERIDFROMACCOUNT1
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/codecommit_rsa

#Use this User ID and ssh-key for repo B
Host git-codecommit.*.amazonaws.com
  User IAMUSERFROMANOTHERAWSACCOUNT
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/codecommit_rsa
```

I have browsed everywhere without finding the right answer. Thanks in advance for any help on this topic.

Regards

Answer (score 12):

You are on the right track :-). You need to modify your config file and make a Host entry for each User/IdentityFile pair. For example:

```
Host git-account1 
  User IAMUSERIDFROMACCOUNT1 
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/codecommit
  HostName git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
Host git-account2 
  User IAMUSERIDFROMACCOUNT2
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/codecommit
  HostName git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
Host git-account3 
  User IAMUSERIDFROMACCOUNT3
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/codecommit
  HostName git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

Your git command lines would look like this:

> git clone ssh://git-account1/v1/repos/AccountOneRepo
>
> git clone ssh://git-account2/v1/repos/AccountTwoRepo
>
> git clone ssh://git-account3/v1/repos/AccountThreeRepo

Comment: What should you use for "git-accoint-n"? as AWS is not accepting the connection that way.

Comment: What does your config file look like? ssh will translate the Host value into the HostName value.

Comment: right now it looks like this:  `Host git-codecommit.*.amazonaws.com
     User APKAEIBAERJR2EXAMPLE
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/codecommit_rsa`

Comment: You need to replace that with the config from above. The Host line would be whatever alias you want. Inside the stanza, you would include HostName git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com.

Comment: Value for "git-account1?" is the AWS user account name (or an alias).

Comment: Not IAMUSERIDFROMACCOUNT1 - should be SSHPUBLICKEYIDFROMACCOUNT1

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

You need to change SSH Key ID. SSH Kye ID you can get from IAM Users -> select_user -> security_credentials-> SSH Key ID

> file name ~/.ssh/config

```
Host git-codecommit.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com 
  User <SSH Key ID> 
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  HostName git-codecommit.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com
Host git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com 
  User <SSH Key ID> 
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  HostName git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you have entered the complete path of the repo in the HOST instead of the Code Commit Repo FQDN public endpoint within the "~/.ssh/config" :-

```
[user@example.com .ssh]# cat config

    Host git-codecommit.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/myrepoXYZ--> ??
      User APKAEIBAERJR2EXAMPLE
      IdentityFile ~/.ssh/codecommit_rsa


[user@example.com .ssh]# git clone ssh://APKAEIBAERJR2EXAMPLE@git- 
 codecommit.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/myrepoXYZ
 Cloning into 'my-webpage'...
 Permission denied (publickey).
 fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
 Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
 exists.





[user@example.com .ssh]# cat config
Host git-codecommit.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com **---> CORRECT **
User APKAEIBAERJR2EXAMPLE
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/codecommit_rsa


[user@example.com .ssh]#  git clone ssh://APKAEIBAERJR2EXAMPLE@git- 
codecommit.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/myrepoXYZ
Cloning into 'my-webpage'...
remote: Counting objects: 12, done.
Receiving objects: 100% (12/12), done.
[root@ip-10-0-6-161 .ssh]# ll
total 36
```

**Detailed Steps are provided in below AWS documentation:-**

[Setup steps for SSH connections to AWS CodeCommit repositories on Linux](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-ssh-unixes.html#setting-up-ssh-unixes-keys)

**1. Step 1:- generate a ssh key on the EC2**

```
[user@example.com .ssh]# ssh-keygen
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/root/.ssh/id_rsa): 
**/root/.ssh/codecommit_rsa**
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in /root/.ssh/codecommit_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /root/.ssh/codecommit_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
SHA256:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
The key's randomart image is:
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

**2. Step 2:-**

create you credentials using ssh-keygen and upload the public key to an IAM user in the
**"SSH keys for AWS CodeCommit"** section

```
[user@example.com .ssh]# ll ~/.ssh/
total 36
-rw------- 1 root root 1679 Mar 16 02:06 codecommit_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  432 Mar 16 02:06 codecommit_rsa.pub ----> *** upload to IAM ***
```

**3. Step 3:-**

Your  ~/.ssh/config file should be:-

```
[user@example.com .ssh]# pwd
/root/.ssh

    [user@example.com .ssh]# cat config
    Host git-codecommit.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com
      User APKAEIBAERJR2EXAMPLE
      IdentityFile ~/.ssh/codecommit_rsa
```

Note: your DNS FQDN public endpoint for AWS CodeCommit can be anything, above is in sydney: ap-southeast-2 region, check yours from the clone drop down in the codecommit console. OR just use a wildcard for allowing codecommit

[AWS CodeCommit Clone URL - SSH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIQ0k.png)